# Publishing long running services in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api, geoprocessing-service

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.2.

I published a lot services for geoprocessing. Most of them are the long running services. Those services manipulate data but user do not wait for the results. When I use REST Submit Job in the web browser sometimes it works without errors, but more often my processes are cancelled. In the web browser I get esriJobMessageTypeInformative that the service was canceled and aborted by User. This is very annoying behavior because I cannot find the reason of this state. Another strange thing is a time of canceling. There is no rule when the process is aborted, sometimes after 4 hours, sometimes after 45 min.  This is not the problem with pooling because I have never reached any of maximum times.

How do I solve this?

Comment: If it never fails via REST endpoint, but it does via your client side app, then perhaps this is an issue with the GP service failing when being hit by multiple users.  Enable 'show messages' on your GP service, and edit your Q to include some of the logs/messages during a fail.

Comment: Was the problem resolved in by some workflow? I have the same problem too and cannot find a solution. Thank you.